# Dynamic substrings on List. 10 elements before variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, substring

I have problem with dynamic substrings. I have list which can have 1000 elements, 100 elements or even 20. I want to make copy of that list, which will have elements from -10 to variable. 
For example(pseudo-code):

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
variable = 12
print L[substring:variable]
>>> L = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12]
```

I can't figure out how make it correct. The point is that variable is always changing by one.

Here is my piece of code:

```
def Existing(self, Pages):
     if(self.iter <= 10):
         list = self.other_list[:self.iter]
     else:
         list = self.other_list[self.iter-10:self.iter]
     result = 0
     page = Pages[0]

     list.reverse()

     for blocks in Pages:
         if(list.index(blocks) > result):
             result = list.index(blocks)
             page = blocks

     return page
```

That method is looking for the element which has the farest index.
This part can be unclear. So assume that we have

```
list = [1,2,3,4,1,5,2,1,2,3,4]
```

Method should return 5, because it is the farest element. List has duplicates and .index() is returning index of the first element so i reverse list. With that code sometimes program returns that some element do not exist in List. The problem (after deep review with debbuger) is with substrings in self.other_list.

Could you help me with that problem? How to make it correct? Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: Because my problem is not clear enough (I was sure that it can be), so here are more examples.

Okay, so list Pages are list which cointains currently pages which are used. Second list "list" are list of all pages which HAS BEEN used. Method is looking for pages which are already used and choose that one which has been not used for the longest time. With word "use" I mean the index of element. What means the farest element? That one which the smallest index (remember about duplicates, the last duplicates means the real index).

So we have:

```
Pages = [1,3,5,9]
```

and

```
list = [1,2,5,3,6,3,5,1,2,9,3,2]
```

Method should return 5.

To sum up:
I'm looking for substring which give result:

```
With list =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20] 
For variable 12: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12] 
for 13: [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13]
```

ect :-)
I know that problem can be complicated. So i would aks you to focus only about substrings. :-) Thanks you very much!

Comment: To be more clear, that method is searching elements which hasn't been used for the longest time in LRU page replecement algorithm.

Comment: So, the list items are always sorted?

Comment: There are never sorted. List contains random ints from 0,9. With my example above I wanted just show how substrings should behave.

Comment: You should provide some more examples, requirements are not clear enough.

Comment: I hope now is more clear. Thank you!

Comment: One last clarification, what if the starting list was: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,11,12,12,12,13,13,14,15,12,16,17,18,19,20]` ?

Comment: If the variable was for example 12: It should be 
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,11]. Variable is index.
If 13 it should be [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,11,12]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly you want to find the index of items from pages that is at minimum position in `lst`(taking duplicates in consideration).

So, for this you need to first reverse the list and then first the index of each item in pages in lst, if item is not found then return negative Infinity. Out of those indices you can find the max item and you'll get your answer.

```
from functools import partial

pages = [1,3,5,9]
lst = [1,2,5,3,6,3,5,1,2,9,3,2]

def get_index(seq, i):
    try:
        return seq.index(i)
    except ValueError:
        return float('-inf')


lst.reverse()
print max(pages, key=partial(get_index, lst))
#5
```

---

Note that the above method will take quadratic time, so it won't perform well for huge lists. If you're not concerned with some additional memory but linear time then you can use set and dict for this:

```
pages_set = set(pages)
d = {}
for i, k in enumerate(reversed(lst), 1):
    if k not in d and k in pages_set:
        d[k] = len(lst) - i

print min(d, key=d.get)
#5
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it wasn't what I have asked for. Code with dict is tricky and I will use it(thanks a lot!), but the point is that how to make pages(which can have huge number of elements) smaller by substrings as I ask in first post :-).

Comment: @Ojmeny Ah! I thought the last example posted by you was related to the first one. For a single number(12 in your case) it is very easy to find its position in the list, but then you're also saying variable is always changing by one. So, what you'll be your expected output if variable is say 12, 13, 14, 15 etc sequentially.

Comment: With  list =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
For variable 12: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12]
for 13: [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,13] ect :-)

Thank you Ashwini :-)

Comment: @Ojmeny Please add your response to question body.